# Problem control tabbing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press Ctrl Tab the windows cycle through most recently used order.
This is winding me up!

So I read up the solution:

To achieve this in Visual Studio Code, you have to edit keybindings.json. Use the Command Palette with CTRL+SHIFT+P, enter "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)", and hit Enter.

Then add to the end of the file:

```
[
// ...
{
"key": "ctrl+tab",
"command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
},
{
"key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
"command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"
}
]
```

That's all good. But then when I try to edit the file, I get this message 'Cannot edit in read-only mode editor'.
OK... so I'll use another editor. I right click on the tab and there is an option 'Open in other editor...' (or something like that). When I click that, nothing happens.

When I search for solutions on 'Cannot edit in read-only mode editor' I get answers to other problems.

- I have searched for a file called keybindings.json - can't find it.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

To be able to control the CTRL Tab action

Comment: Try opening the GUI part of the settings responsible for that - `Ctrl+K Ctrl+S` (the command is named `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`); from there you can either either change those shortcuts or you can open the JSON file (to do the latter you can press `Ctrl+O` by default or look for the icon in the right end of the tab bar).

Comment: @KamenMinkov AMAZING! I've spent sooo much time suffering with this! Now solved. 

>>  from there you can either either change those shortcuts
I can edit and add new values - but wasn't sure what to put in?
Would I for example put: "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"

Right now, the old entries are still there. But it works now after I pasted in the contents:

{
"key": "ctrl+tab",
"command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
},
{
"key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
"command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"
}

Comment: I think they're evaluated in order (so if you repeat something, the last thing takes precedence) and if you override a default shortcut through the GUI, it would explicitly write a binding that unbinds the command, i.e. same command, but with a minus in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm unsure how to mark this question as solved and to give you 5 stars for the answer? 

Comment: Posted these as an answer (and not a comment), you can mark it as a solution if you want. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Open the GUI part of the settings responsible for that - `Ctrl+K Ctrl+S` (the command is named `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`); from there you can either either change those shortcuts or you can open the JSON file (to do the latter you can press `Ctrl+O` by default or look for the icon in the right end of the tab bar).

As for the JSON, I think the bindings there are evaluated in order (so if you repeat something, the last thing takes precedence) and if you override a default shortcut through the GUI, it would explicitly write a binding that unbinds the command, i.e. same command, but with a minus in front of it.